# How to take a long string and scroll it in a 15 character text control/label?

Tags: c#, winforms, text, scroll

I am trying to take the lyrics of a song and scroll it in a label, but I want the label to only show 15 characters at a time. It would be like a steady scroll to the end of the song. How would I go about doing this? I have looked everywhere but I can't seem to find anything on this.

Comment: And what kind of desktop app? Windows forms? WPF? Silverlight?

Comment: you say you've looked, but have you actually tried to write something for yourself?

Comment: desktop app, windows form, and yes i have tried to write something myself but i cant figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Construct a loop that sets the `.Text` property of the label. Each iteration of the loop should increment by however many characters you want to scroll per iteration.

```
string Lyrics = "This song is just six words long";
int CurrentPosition = 0;
const int CharactersToShow = 15;
for (int i = 0; i < Lyrics.Length; i++)
{
    lblOutput.Text = CharactersToShow + CurrentPosition > Lyrics.Length
                ? Lyrics.Substring(CurrentPosition)
                : Lyrics.Substring(CurrentPosition, CharactersToShow);
    CurrentPosition++;
    lblOutput.Update();
    Thread.Sleep(250);
}
```

Some notes: This is just an example. As written, it monopolizes the GUI thread because it is almost always in sleep.

Instead of a sleep delay you would probably want to use a timer which updates the label every tick.

Comment: ty exactly what i am look for but is there a way for it to start over after it finishes?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial for creating a text scrolling effect in WinForms: http://www.dotnettutorials.com/tutorials/windowsprogramming/text-scroll-effect-cs.aspx

Also, there is a WinForms marquee control on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24587/Easy-to-Use-Marquee-Control-for-Windows-Form-with

Comment: that doesn't do what i want that takes the first letter and moves it to the back i want it to take a string of like 100 characters and scroll it showing 15 characters at a time so it would like stream the lyrics

Answer (score 1):

Have the form use a stopwatch which calls an update method every n milliseconds. In the update method, change the text in the label by k characters. Vary k and n to match the timing of the song.